# How can I use an XSD schema in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, xsd

such a question: I have a xsd file. I need to generate an xml file, pre-filled with data.

I need to do all this in Laravel, since I need to implement this functionality in the project

what is the principle approach to use?

I started doing this:

- parse xsd, get an array
- based on this array in the db, I create the primary structure of the future xml
- then, based on this structure, I assemble the form through vue components (each complexType has its own component)
- through the components I enter data into the database (create new tags, delete, add attribute and more)
- then, when I need to get the xml, I get the data from the db and collect the xml from them

is this correct?

the problem is that there can be a lot of xsd schemes (and I have only done one for one so far), and this will complicate the support of the functionality

perhaps there are some libraries that generate html forms from xsd?

Or is there any other PHP solution?

thanks to all

P.S. example my XSD (without the complexTope part and all the SimpleType (because they didn’t fit due to the restriction)) ↓

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- Основной элемент -->

    <xs:element name="ExplanatoryNote">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Корневой элемент - пояснительная записка</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ExplanatoryNoteNumber" type="non-empty-string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Шифр пояснительной записки</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ExplanatoryNoteYear" type="tYear" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Год составления пояснительной записки</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ExplanatoryNoteModifications" type="tExplanatoryNoteModifications" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о внесении изменений в проектную документацию</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:key name="ModificationKey">
                        <xs:selector xpath="Modification"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="ModificationNumber"/>
                    </xs:key>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="IssueAuthor" type="tAuthor" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о лице, подготовившем пояснительную записку - генеральном проектировщике</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ProjectDocumentationAuthors" type="tProjectDocumentationAuthors" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения об индивидуальных предпринимателях и (или) юридических лицах, подготовивших проектную документацию (кроме генерального проектировщика)</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Signers" type="tSigners" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о лицах, подписавших документацию</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Developer" type="tDeveloper">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о застройщике</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="TechnicalCustomer" type="tTechnicalCustomer">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о техническом заказчике</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="UsedAbbreviations" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Список используемых сокращений</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="UsedNorms" type="tUsedNorms" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Перечень документов по стандартизации, используемых полностью или частично на добровольной основе для соблюдения требований технических регламентов (из числа документов по стандартизации, включенных в перечни документов в области стандартизации, в результате применения которых на добровольной основе обеспечивается соблюдение требований технических регламентов)</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ProjectDecisionDocuments" type="tDocuments" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Перечень документов, на основании которых принято решение о подготовке проектной документации</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ProjectInitialDocuments" type="tDocuments" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Перечень исходно-разрешительной документации, кроме отчетной документации по результатам инженерных изысканий</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="EngineeringSurveyDocuments" type="tEngineeringSurveyDocuments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Перечень отчетной документации по результатам инженерных изысканий</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="AdditionalData" type="tAdditionalData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Дополнительные материалы, не предусмотренные Положением о составе разделов проектной документации и требованиях к их содержанию, утвержденному Постановлением Правительства Российской Федерации №87 от 16.02.2008</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="FinanceSources" type="tFinanceSources" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения об источниках финансирования строительства (реконструкции, капитального ремонта, сноса) объекта капитального строительства</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="NonIndustrialObject" type="tNonIndustrialObject" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Описание объекта капитального строительства непроизводственного назначения</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:key name="NonIndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKey">
                            <xs:selector xpath=".//Document"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="DocNumber"/>
                        </xs:key>
                        <xs:keyref name="EnergyEfficiencyNonIndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKeyRef" refer="NonIndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKey">
                            <xs:selector xpath="./EnergyEfficiencyLinks/ProjectDocumentationLink"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="DocNumber"/>
                        </xs:keyref>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="IndustrialObject" type="tIndustrialObject" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Описание объекта капитального строительства производственного назначения</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:key name="IndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKey">
                            <xs:selector xpath=".//Document"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="DocNumber"/>
                        </xs:key>
                        <xs:keyref name="EnergyEfficiencyIndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKeyRef" refer="IndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKey">
                            <xs:selector xpath="./EnergyEfficiencyLinks/ProjectDocumentationLink"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="DocNumber"/>
                        </xs:keyref>
                        <xs:keyref name="IndustrialSafetyIndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKeyRef" refer="IndustrialObjectProjectDocumentKey">
                            <xs:selector xpath="./IndustrialSafetyLinks/ProjectDocumentationLink"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="DocNumber"/>
                        </xs:keyref>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="LinearObject" type="tLinearObject" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Описание линейного объекта капитального строительства </xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:key name="LinearObjectProjectDocumentKey">
                            <xs:selector xpath=".//Document"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="DocNumber"/>
                        </xs:key>
                        <xs:keyref name="IndustrialSafetyLinearObjectProjectDocumentKeyRef" refer="LinearObjectProjectDocumentKey">
                            <xs:selector xpath="./IndustrialSafetyLinks/ProjectDocumentationLink"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="DocNumber"/>
                        </xs:keyref>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="DesignerNote" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Дополнительное произвольное текстовое описание, подготовленное разработчиком проектной документации</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DesignerAssurance" type="tDesignerAssurance" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Заверение проектной организации о том, что проектная документация разработана в соответствии с градостроительным планом земельного участка, заданием на проектирование, градостроительным регламентом, документами об использовании земельного
                            участка для строительства (в случае если на земельный участок не распространяется действие градостроительного регламента или в отношении его не устанавливается градостроительный регламент), техническими регламентами, в том числе устанавливающими требования по обеспечению
                            безопасной эксплуатации зданий, строений, сооружений и безопасного использования прилегающих к ним территорий, и с соблюдением технических условий</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>

            <xs:attribute name="SchemaVersion" type="tSchemaVersion" use="required" fixed="01.03">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Номер версии схемы, используемой при создании пояснительной записки</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>

            <xs:attribute name="SchemaLink" type="non-empty-string" use="optional">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Ссылка на xml-схему на официальном сайте, где опубликована схема</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>

            <xs:attribute name="id" type="tGUID" use="optional">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Идентификатор блока данных "ExplanatoryNote" (для организации возможности использования XMLDsig в части подписания)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>

            <xs:attribute name="AccessRestriction" type="non-empty-string" use="optional">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Гриф ограничения доступа к пояснительной записке</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>

        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="ClimateDistrictUnique">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//ClimateConditions/ClimateDistrict"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>

        <xs:unique name="GeologicalConditionsKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//ClimateConditions/GeologicalConditions"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>

        <xs:unique name="WindDistrictKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//ClimateConditions/WindDistrict"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>

        <xs:unique name="SnowDistrictKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//ClimateConditions/SnowDistrict"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>

        <xs:unique name="SeismicActivityKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//ClimateConditions/SeismicActivity"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>

        <xs:unique name="StageNameKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//Stage"/>
            <xs:field xpath="Number"/>
        </xs:unique>

        <xs:unique name="RoutesNameKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//Route"/>
            <xs:field xpath="Name"/>
        </xs:unique>

    </xs:element>

    <!-- Описание сложных типов -->

    <xs:complexType name="tNonIndustrialObject">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Описание объекта капитального строительства непроизводственного назначения</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="non-empty-string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Наименование объекта капитального строительства</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ConstructionType" type="tConstructionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Вид работ, на который разрабатывается проектная документация</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ConstructionDuration" type="tPositiveDecimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Продолжительность работ, месяц</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ConstructionDates" type="tConstructionDates" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о сроках строительства, вводе в эксплуатацию</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Address" type="tAddress" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Почтовый (строительный) адрес объекта капитального строительства или местоположение</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Functions" type="tFunctions" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о функциональном назначении объекта капитального строительства, состав и характеристику производства, номенклатуру выпускаемой продукции (работ, услуг)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="FunctionsFeatures" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о принадлежности к объектам транспортной инфраструктуры и к другим объектам, функционально-технологические особенности которых влияют на их безопасность</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PowerIndicator" type="tTEI" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Данные о проектной мощности объекта капитального строительства</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="TEI" type="tTEI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Технико-экономические показатели проектируемого объекта капитального строительства</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="EnergyEfficiency" type="tEnergyEfficiency" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о классе энергетической эффективности (в случае, если присвоение класса энергетической эффективности объекту капитального строительства является обязательным в соответствии с законодательством Российской Федерации об энергосбережении) и о
                        повышении энергетической эффективности</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="FireDangerCategory" type="tFireDangerCategory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Категория пожарной и взрывопожарной опасности</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="PeoplePermanentStay" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о наличии помещений с постоянным пребыванием людей</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="ResponsibilityLevel" type="tResponsibilityLevel" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Уровень ответственности</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ObjectParts" type="tObjectParts" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о составных частях объекта, в случае если объект сложный</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="ClimateConditions" type="tClimateConditions" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о климатической, географической и инженерно-геологической характеристике района, на территории которого предполагается осуществлять строительство (реконструкцию, капитальный ремонт, снос) объекта капитального
                        строительства</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Resources" type="tResources" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о потребности объекта капитального строительства в топливе, газе, воде и электрической энергии</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="RenewableSourceInfo" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения об использовании возобновляемых источников энергии и вторичных энергетических ресурсов</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LandCategory" type="tLandCategory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о категории земель, на которых располагается (будет располагаться) объект капитального строительства</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LandInfo" type="tLandInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о земельных участках, изымаемых для государственных или муниципальных нужд, о земельных участках, в отношении которых устанавливается сервитут, публичный сервитут, обоснование их размеров, если такие размеры не установлены нормами отвода
                        земель для конкретных видов деятельности, или правилами землепользования и застройки, или проектами планировки, проектами межевания территории, - при необходимости изъятия земельного участка для государственных или муниципальных нужд, установления сервитута, публичного
                        сервитута</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LandFunds" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о размере средств, требующихся для возмещения убытков правообладателям земельных участков и (или) для внесения в качестве арендной платы, платы за сервитут, публичный сервитут и (или) для выкупа земельных участков, - в случаях,
                        установленных законодательством Российской Федерации</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PatentsUsed" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения об использованных в проекте изобретениях, результатах проведенных патентных исследований</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="SpecialRequirements" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о наличии разработанных и согласованных специальных технических условий - в случае необходимости разработки таких условий</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="StaffNote" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Данные о численности работников на объекте капитального строительства и их профессионально-квалификационном составе, числе рабочих мест и другие данные, установленные заданием на проектирование и характеризующие объект капитального
                        строительства</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="SoftwareUsed" type="tSoftwareUsed" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о компьютерных программах, которые использовались при выполнении расчетов конструктивных элементов зданий, строений и сооружений</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="StagesInfo" type="tStagesInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Обоснование возможности осуществления строительства, реконструкции объекта капитального строительства по этапам строительства, реконструкции с выделением этих этапов </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="DestroyFunds" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о предполагаемых затратах, связанных со сносом зданий и сооружений, переселением людей, переносом сетей инженерно-технического обеспечения</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="EnergyEfficiencyLinks" type="tProjectDocumentationLinks" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о разделах и пунктах проектной документации, содержащих решения и мероприятия по обеспечению соблюдения требований энергетической эффективности и оснащенности зданий, строений, сооружений приборами учета используемых энергетических
                        ресурсов</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LandReclamationLink" type="tTextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о наличии проекта рекультивации земель</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ProjectDocumentation" type="tNonLinearProjectDocumentContent" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Сведения о составе проектной документации объекта непроизводственного назначения</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Model" type="tModel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="ru">Представление модели объекта</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>

        <xs:attribute ref="ObjectID" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="Placement" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="DangerousAndComplex" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="Unique" use="optional"/>

    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```